# Laravel nested blade component

Tags: laravel

I want to do this but can't find any documentation about how to render components inside components

```
   <x-accordion>
            <x-accordion-tab />
            <x-accordion-tab />
            <x-accordion-tab />
            <x-accordion-tab />
            <x-accordion-tab />
   </x-accordion>
```

Accordion

```
<div class="accordion-tabs">

</div>
```

Accordion Tab

```
<div class="accordion-tab">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chck1" class="accordion-nav">
    <label class="accordion-tab-label" for="chck1">Item 1</label>
    <div class="accordion-tab-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [blade#slots](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#slots)

```php
<div class="accordion-tabs">
     {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... I feel stupid cause i was just looking at slots but I thought this was just html content. Documentation is really lacking